# Jmockit dependency with jdk11

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automation, jmockit

I am using JDK 11 in my project and tried a couple of versions of jmockit jar, but I am facing a dependency issue. I have tried versions from 1.9 to 1.49.

Can someone help me, which one is a compatible version of jmockit with JDK 11?

Comment: I am also looking same qustion

Comment: I am using JMockit 1.49 with JDK 11, no problems.

Comment: hi @Rogério  i was able to solve by passing vm javaagent  information. by any chance are you running with ANT build?

Comment: No, I running it with Maven.

Answer (score 0):

(**UPDATED**: FEB-2024)  The original maintainers of JMockit hit personal issues at the onset of the pandemic and updates to org.jmockit:jmockit have essentially stopped.  Meanwhile, some kind folks have taken the code further over at https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.github.hazendaz.jmockit/jmockit (currently, v1.52).  I use 1.52 with Java 17 on a daily basis, and would guess it works with higher versions (Java 21?) as well.

---

JMockit 1.49 with JDK11 works for some/many/most people, but there is at least one known issue (https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/688) that is a blocker for some of us.

Contributor activity on the project has also fallen off, and it's not clear what's going on with this project.  https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/graphs/commit-activity   I'm hopeful things will get back to normal as JMockit is the best mocking framework out there.